# WAP, How to Publish to Web with Web Deploy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hosting, web-deployment, vs-web-application-project

I want to publish my web application on a hosting server.

```
Domain:  mysite.com
Folder:  mysite.com/TestWAP
```

1. Can I use one-click deployment on typical discount shared hosting?
2. Will I need to make any installation on the server first, and how is
   this done?
3. With the above details, what would I specify in the
   "Service URL" and "Site/Application" fields?

Comment: I have other sites on the server so wanted to avoid making a mess by brute trial and error. Hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these resources:

[How to: Deploy a Web Application Project Using One-Click Publish and Web Deploy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx)

[Walkthrough: Deploying a Web Application Project Using One-Click Publish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd984948.aspx)

[ASP.NET Web Application Project Deployment FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Build, publish local with a manual first time setup on shared host. From then on publish through Visual Studio Publish - FTP option.

Comment: Why it's not suited to use Web Deploy?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.

[Configure the Web Deployment Handler](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/516/configure-the-web-deployment-handler/)

Hope this help.